# jquery PJAX/AJAX preventDefault() not blocking link from being clicked

Tags: jquery, keyboard-events, preventdefault, pjax

I'd like to prevent PJAX clicking of a link unless an input box is keyed up.

Here's the code:

```
$('a.pjax').pjax({container: '#main_content'}).live('click', function(event){ 
   if(keyed){ 
        console.log('yes, you typed');
   }
   else if(keyed==false){
        console.log('no, please type something');
        event.preventDefault();                                                 
   }
});
```

My problem is that despite the condition being determined correctly, PJAX still loads the page regardless of the `preventDefault()`.

Any thoughts on why this is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the pjax function will always fire with the set-up you have in place.

However, the following should work:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.pjax', function (event) {
    if (keyed) {
        console.log('yes, you typed');
        return $.pjax.click(event, '#main_content');
    }
    else {
        console.log('no, please type something');
        return false;
    }
});
```